# Does Android Chrome supports <audio /> tag?

Tags: android, audio, google-chrome, tags

Is it possible to play continuous audio stream (MP3 / AAC) in Android browser using `<audio />` tag?

If you're not sure, could you at least recommend some good testing page containing and using `<audio />` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/400dc61d41530242?pli=1) discussion, Android browser doesn't support the audio tag.

But according to [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=83#c34) discussion, it is possible to do media streaming. (see comment #34)

Google term I used:

1. [audio tag android browser](http://www.google.com/search?q=audio+tag+Android+browser)
2. [streaming audio via android browser](http://www.google.com/search?&q=streaming+audio+via+android+browser)

Comment: Haha, now both of those google searches point into **this question** as first result!

Answer (score 2):

FYI, here is a test page for audio tag - http://www.jplayer.org/HTML5.Audio.Support/